# image_tag in mailer not using asset_host

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

image_tag isn't using the asset_host I've set. Any ideas why? The only thing I can think of is it having to do with it being a Mailer.

**config/environment/development.rb**

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
```

**myMailer.rb**

```
<%= image_tag "logo.png", :style=>"margin-left:10px; padding-bottom:15px;" %>
```

**rendered as:**

```
<img alt="Logo" src="/images/logo.png?1303090162" style="margin-left:10px; padding-bottom:15px;" />
```

**In console:**

```
> MyApp::Application.config.action_controller
#<OrderedHash {… :asset_host=>"http://localhost:3000", …}>
```

I need the image_tag to create a full path url because it will be showing up in an email.

Comment: try to assign asset host in following way and see if it works
ActionController::Base.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"

Comment: According to my research that was used for Rails2, not Rails3.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html here they used it to set asset host and the rails version is 3.07

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I was wrong before.  This is the solution you need (until rails 3.1 where the asset_host configurations become unified):

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
```

Comment: It doesn't appear it was ever unified. On Rails 3.2.8 I'm still having to set this separately to the `action_controller` config.

Comment: There's a shortcut for this in at least Rails 3.2: `config.asset_host = 'localhost:3000'`.  It sets both `config.action_controller.asset_host` and `config.action_mailer.asset_host`.

Comment: Seems like this is still necessary for rails 4.

Comment: Still necessary even in Rails 5.

Comment: Even in Rails 7 :)

Answer (score 22):

We need to specify both config.action_controller.asset_host and config.action_mailer.asset_host, on Rails 3.1 and 3.2.

To add the hostname to the image_tag on both e-mail and non-email views, add the following to your environment file:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
config.action_mailer.asset_host = config.action_controller.asset_host
```

Where 'http://localhost:3000' should be replaced by your host URL (and port if applicable).

This needs to be set on both action_controller and action_mailer, even in Rails 3.2.x.

Comment: why we need `config.action_controller.asset_host` to specify, is it different form `config.action_mailer.asset_host` ?

Comment: One is to set the asset manager for action view, the other for action mailer. You need to specify both in order for the web pages and email templates to work.

Answer (score 0):

The offending code as to why you can't do it is here:

```
# actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_paths.rb, line 27
def compute_public_path(source, dir, ext = nil, include_host = true)
  # More code up here....

    if controller && include_host
      has_request = controller.respond_to?(:request)
      source = rewrite_host_and_protocol(source, has_request)
    end
end
```

Here is the offending file on GH: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_paths.rb

Since an ActionMailer View template lacks a Controller, you don't get the command to rewrite based on an asset_host.  This should probably be a ticket opened to the Rails core team.

You can try the following config and see if it helps:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host=>"localhost", :port=>3000, :protocol=>"http://"}
```

I'm pretty sure it's only going to work for `url_for` though.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it only works for url_for. Wish there was a way to do image_tag url_for("logo.png")…

Comment: I'll see if I can scrap together some time to write a patch for it.