# How to display image assets in Rails 3.1 email views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I have a Rails 3.1 (rc6) app with some HTML emails.

I'm trying to display some inline images in an HTML email message. **How do I get `image_tag` to use the proper absolute URL to my image asset?** (i.e. I want it to give me `http://myproductionserver.com/assets/email_tile-89eda655d6fdd07de75f56547a4a4041.jpg` instead of just `/assets/email_tile-89eda655d6fdd07de75f56547a4a4041.jpg`)

(I tried setting config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://myproductionserver.com" in my production.rb file but then it just renders an image URL with out the proper asset pipeline name)

**EDIT:** this also raises the question of expired asset URLs in old emails. Will images in emails be broken after a deploy?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739819/image-tag-in-mailer-not-using-asset-host

Answer (score 0):

I believe you actually need to set your action_controller.asst_hosts:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host =  "http://myproductionserver.com"
```